# Generic collection in generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a custom class (let's call it `MyClass`) that looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<MyClass> list;
    private object data;
}
```

However, I want to get rid of the `object` property and instead use a generic class. So something like this:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    private List<MyClass<T>> list;
    private T data;
}
```

However, I am in need for this behavior:

```
MyClass<Foo> foo = new MyClass<Foo>;
foo.list = new List<MyClass<Bar>>;
```

So I need to be able to have different datatypes for the foo-instance and the list/data-property in foo. But the T's in the generic example will be the same and only allow this:

```
MyClass<Foo> foo = new MyClass<Foo>;
foo.list = new List<MyClass<Foo>>;
```

Each item in foo.list will again have a list that might be of a different type. By the time I compile `MyClass` I have no knowledge about what datatypes will be in the lists/data-property or how many levels there will be. How can I build this flexible structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics are designed to allow for the compiler to perform checks on type usage and they also provide some nifty additional benefits.

What you've described cannot be achieved with generics, if each time you're updating `list` with a list of a potentially different type then generics cannot help you.

However, if each of these types share a common base type or share a common interface then you could use that as your `T` for the list and that would allow you to use them.

If however each instance of `MyClass` allows only one type of List of `MyClass<?>` then you could revise `MyClass` as such:

```
public class MyClass<T, TList>
{
    private List<MyClass<T, TList>> list;
    private T data;
}
```

Comment: But with that solution, the data-property of ALL children will be MyClass<T> and the items in the list of EVERY children will be MyClass<TList>, right? I use MyClass to display items in a treeview and want to attach the actual data object to each node -> In theory every node needs to be able to have a different type.

Comment: @Jan then if every one of them needs to be of different types you've misunderstood the point of generics, and you'll be better off using `List<object>`. Without actual code you're using and actual usage we don't have much to go on except theory.

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this goal with just one class. You will have to build one generic base class for each level with children, one base class for the lowest level without children and one derived class per hierarchy level.

The base classes would look like this:

```
public class MyClass<TData>
{
    public TData Data { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass<TData, TDataChildren, TChildren> : MyClass<TData>
    where TChildren : MyClass<TDataChildren>
{
    public List<TChildren> List { get; set; }
}
```

The derived classes per Level would look like this:

```
public class Level0 : MyClass<Foo, Bar, Level1> { }

public class Level1 : MyClass<Bar, Fubar, Level2> { }

public class Level2 : MyClass<Fubar> { }
```

Usage:

```
var root = new Level0();
root.Data = new Foo();
root.List = new List<Level1>
{
    new Level1()
    {
        Data = new Bar(),
        List = new List<Level2>
        {
            new Level2()
            {
                Data = new Fubar()
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but it's not exactly what I am looking for. In theory there can be a huge amount of different levels. Sticking with a data-object of type `object` seems to be easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Add a second type in MyClass.

```
public class MyClass<T, G>
{
    private List<MyClass<G, T>> list;
    private T data;
}
```

This is assuming that you don't care the type of the nested list inside your list.

But can you elaborate a bit more on the utility of your code because it is hard to tel just with abstract data.

Comment: What should it give? It is the solution for only two types. I think OP wants to pass different types in his generic class

Comment: Anyway as @Clint point out there is no way to achieve what you want. Your type does have a infinite recursion definition and since you are using a statically type language you need to end the recursion at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to implement a very similar thing in C++ right now and am running into the same problem. The problem with templates is that they are strongly typed and `MyClass<foo>` is treated as a complete different and unrelated type as `MyClass<bar>`.

What I am playing with now is creating an abstract class that has pure virtual methods on it like `GetInt`, `GetDouble`, `GetBool`, `GetString`. I then want to have a templated `Add` that will instantiate the appropriate concrete class and add it to my vector. I'm not sure if it will work, but it's along these lines:

```
class Data
{
public:
    template<typename T> Add(const std::string& key, const T& val)
    {
         Data* pData = NULL;

         //test the type using std::numeric_limits to figure out which concrete
         //type to use.

         m_mapValues[key] = pData;
    }

protected:

    virtual int GetInt() const = 0;
    virtual unsigned int GetUINT() const = 0;
    virtual std::string GetString() const = 0;
    //blah blah more types that you want to handle

private:

    std::map<std::string,Data*> m_mapValues;
};

class UINTData : public Data
{
    //implement pure virtual methods.
}
```

This is obviously incomplete, but I hope it gives you some ideas.