# Implementing collection of a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I am trying to create a custom class like this as follows.

```
public MyClass<T> 
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public T Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
}
```

The value of T could be either string or int or datetime .I assume i can create new instance of this class like

```
MyClass<int> intclass = new MyClass<int>();
MyClass<String> stringclass=new MyClass<String>();
```

and so forth.

Is it possible to create a collection of the above classes where i can put intclass and stringclass into a custom collection.

Comment: do you understand, that you will need to cast `int` and `string` back from object, if you want to put them into one collection?

Comment: Possible duplicate / related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833397/generic-collection-in-generic-class/15833511#15833511

Comment: Thank all for your quick answers...!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to mix different generic types (so have a collection containing both `MyClass<int>` and `MyClass<string>`) you need to define some common base type *or* use a collection that is not strongly typed:

```
public class MyClass<T> : MyClass
{
    public T Value2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can define a collection like:

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
list.Add(new MyClass<int>());
list.Add(new MyClass<string>());
```

You will have to cast results when retrieving entries in order to access their `Value2` property though.

Another option to avoid the base-class is simply to use a `List<object>`:

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();
list.Add(new MyClass<int>());
list.Add(new MyClass<string>());
```

But it's the same problem as above, but plausibly worse (because then you can store *anything* in there)

EDIT: There are various ways of how to allow untyped access to `Value2` in the base non-generic `MyClass`. One way is to define an "untyped" version of it on the base class and override it on the subclass which would perform type-checking:

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public abstract object Value2Untyped { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass<T> : MyClass
{
    public T Value2 { get; set; }

    public override object Value2Untyped
    {
        get
        {
            return Value2;
        }
        set
        {
            Value2 = (T)value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then for all your objects or collections that are typed against the base non-generic `MyClass`, you can still access values, and even set values at runtime. (the `set` of course is optional)

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
List<MyClass<int>> intClassList = new List<MyClass<int>>();
intClassList.Add(new MyClass<int>());
```

Comment: No..your example would only have a collection of base type MyClass<T>...where T is int..i want my custom collection to have a base type of T where T could be int/string/datetime

Comment: I don't know whether this is possible since i see issues with type safety